# How to run Spark Streaming application on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I run a Spark Streaming application on MS Windows 10 64-bit that stores data in MongoDB using [spark-mongo-connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark).

Whenever I run the Spark application, even `pyspark` I get the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-

Full stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:612)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
  ... 32 more
```

I use **Hadoop 3.0.0 alpha1** that I installed myself locally with `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable pointing to the path to Hadoop dir and `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin` in the `PATH` environment variable.

So I tried to do the following:

```
> hdfs dfs -ls /tmp
Found 1 items
drw-rw-rw-   -          0 2016-12-26 16:08 /tmp/hive
```

I tried to change the permissions as follows:

```
hdfs dfs -chmod 777 /tmp/hive
```

but this command outputs:

> WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

I seem to be missing Hadoop's native library for my OS, which after looking it up also appears that i need to recomplie the `libhadoop.so.1.0.0` for 64bit platform.

Where can I find the native library for Windows 10 64-bit?
Or is there another way of solving this ? aprt from the library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't have to install Hadoop to use Spark, including Spark Streaming module with or without MongoDB.

Since you're on Windows there is the known issue with NTFS' POSIX-incompatibility so you have to have `winutils.exe` in `PATH` since Spark does use Hadoop jars under the covers (for file system access). You can download `winutils.exe` from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils. Download one from `hadoop-2.7.1` if you don't know which version you should use (but it should really reflect the version of Hadoop your Spark Streaming was built with, e.g. Hadoop 2.7.x for Spark 2.0.2).

Create `c:/tmp/hive` directory and execute the following as admin (aka **Run As Administrator**):

```
winutils.exe chmod -R 777 \tmp\hive
```

**PROTIP** Read [Problems running Hadoop on Windows](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems) for the Apache Hadoop project's official answer.

The message below is harmless and you can safely disregard it.

`WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform`

Comment: If you have it, make sure that you defined `HADOOP_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables in Control Panel so when you execute your Spark Streaming app, Spark would use `winutils.exe` for its own low-level stuff.

Comment: Actually that did in fact change the permissions,but spark still displays an output of the same exception

Comment: How do you run your Spark app? Can you paste the entire output from the very beginning, after you start your Spark app to the exception? Use gist.github.com to paste the entire output (or paste it to your question if short enough).

Comment: I open an admin cmd then :
`cd C:\spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\bin`


Then i run this `pyspark --conf spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/db_name.collection_name --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.0.0
`

This is the [gist link](https://gist.github.com/MokhFn/570df589abfd9a4d548238b35a5bb584) for the errors

Comment: Can you add `set %HADOOP_HOME%` and `set %PATH%` to the gist? Can you add `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin\winutils.exe ls \tmp\hive` to the gist, too? Remove `--conf` and `--packages` from the command line as they are not needed for now. I think we're closer to find the solution!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131527/discussion-between-jacek-laskowski-and-mrrobot).

Comment: waw thank you, the winutils trick solved it for me, i desperately tried downloading the hadoop-2.7.1 version of winutils, even though i had hadoop 3.0.0 alpha version,i replaced it, and it worked perfectly !